# Symfony - Where to place common code for multiple/all Controllers?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

Let's say my app has multiple pages like

- /home
- /settings
- /blog

For all these I need some common code. Example: Fetching the E-Mail-Address from a logged in user to show it on the top-right of each page, next to a logout button.

So on each and every controller (HomeController, SettingsController, BlogController) I would have to register a twig variable:

e.g.: AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $user_email = Something::getUserEmail();
    ...
    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', array('user_email' => $user_email));
}
```

So the `getUserEmail()` (and probably a lot more business logic) will be the same on all front end controller methods of my app. It would be very redundant to copy the code into each controller method that renders a page. I could register a service but I would have to call it on every controller too. I could also write a BaseController with - let's say `BaseController->init()` - but again, I would have to call this method on every controller method over and over.

**So what is the best practice to place common business logic for multiple/all controllers?**

Bonus: can I "pre-register" twig variables like in smarty or do I have to submit them via `render`? It would be nice to register $user_email only once and not on each controller method as this would again lead to a lot of duplicate code.

Asking for Symfony 3+, 4.

Comment: "So what is the best practice to place common business logic for multiple/all controllers?"

Short answer: by creating services.
Long answer: see Stephan Vierkant post.

Comment: Be aware that accessing user information is a common requirement that is already addressed by the twig bundle.  In almost all cases the need for common controller code actually goes away once you become more comfortable with the framework.

Comment: @Cerad could you provide more information about how User Information can be handled in twig?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/app_variable.html

Comment: @Cerad thank you, this actually answers a lot. But how would I e.g. store a "Cart" variable similar to app.user?

Comment: When I learned Symfony I would just sort of browse through the documentation looking for interesting stuff.  If, for example, I needed to know how to do something in twig I would scan through the twig section.  In fact, even today I often just randomly pick a link and scan it.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: don't make your controller 'fat' and use Dependency Injection instead.

I'm using Symfony for years and I had the same question for a long time. [This article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html) is worth reading. By using many third party libraries and bundles, I saw a common way where to place business logic.

Here's an example of the directory structure of one of my bundles:

```
Appbundle\
    Command
    Controller
    DataFixtures
    Datatables
    Entity
    EventListener
    Exception
    Extension
    Form
    Menu
    Resources\
         views
    Security\
         Authorization\
             Voter
    Template
    Util
    Validator
```

(not all directories are mentioned)

An important part of the business logic is in `Entity`, while the security rules (mainly SecurityVoters) is in `Security\Authorization\Voter`.

For business logic that is not tightly coupled to Symfony Components or Doctrine (like Forms, SecurityVoters and my entity model) I create classes  for a specific goal (keeping Single responsibility principle in mind) and use Services/[Dependency Injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) to use the business logic in my controller:

```
use AppBundle\Mailer\Something;

// ...
public function indexAction()
{
    $mailer = $this->get(Something::class);

    $user_email = $mailer->getUserEmail();

    ...
    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', array('user_email' => $user_email));
}
```

One important rule: [keep your controller slim](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/10/31/symfony2-trimming-fat-from-controllers/). It has only one purpose: getting a Request and send back a Response. Keeping your controllers as slim as possible has a lot of advantages:

- It makes unit tests easier. Testing services is a lot easier than testing controllers.
- You can use the same business logic in your Commands too. After my application got more complicated, I learned that not all things my application did was necessarily initiated by the front controller. For example background tasks: they are initiated by a cron job.
- If you want to have a second front controller (a RESTfull API for your native app/third party access/etc.) you can reuse the services. If you want to switch to another framework you can easily switch and use the Symfony Components too.

For you question about Twig variables, check [How to Inject Variables into all Templates (i.e. global Variables)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html).

Comment: I still find this a bit unintuitive. Let's say I want to show the login user name or cart value of an E-Commerce site. I would have to call the "Cart service" and "User service" on every controller method. Your answer make sense for shared business logic among multiple but few controllers. However for a general code for the whole site I feel it is a lot of copy and paste.

Comment: I think in your case you want to get the user name or cart value from your database, don't you? If so, there is no need for you to use a service for that: just use Doctrine directly from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try the [Traits](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php)? according to the docs

> A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance
> by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several
> independent classes
>
> A Trait is similar to a class, but only intended to group
> functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way

If you does not want Injection or Services this would be a good idea. Symfony is using this approach to.

```
abstract class Controller implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
    use ControllerTrait;
....
}
```

You could check both traits and give it a try.

Hope it helps

Comment: Traits are an easy way to share code between classes, but it's even easier to make a complete mess of your code with them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use standard controller and twig possibilities to achieve this goal. You can create a controller for common actions like rendering an email of logged-in user, and then - in "base.html.twig" - render action's result.

*// CommonController.php*

```
/**
 * @Route("/common/get-email", name="get_email")
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    // ... fetch email in some way ...
    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', array('user_email' => $user_email));
}
```

*// [base.html.twig](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts)*

```
{{ render(url('get_email')) }}
```

Please, consider the [Embedding Controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers) section.